# Deserializar Array JSON em um Array de Objetos

Tags: c#, json, array, serialização, json.net

Boa tarde, resolvi perguntar pois já estou há 3 dias agarrado nisso e por mais que eu tenha procurado, não encontrei uma solução para meu problema. Acesso um Web Service via C#, HttpClient, e obtenho um Json no seguinte formato:

```
{
    "games": [
        {
            "IdJogo": "1",
            "Titulo": "No Man's Sky",
            "DtaLancamento": "Junho 2016",
            "ResumoBR": "Em No Man's Sky  você assume o papel de um     explorador planetário com uma nave espacial, permitindo-lhes explorar a     superfície de vários planetas e interagir com a flora e fauna, e viajar pelo espaço, entrar em combate com forças inimigas e viajar a outros planetas.",
            "NomeImg": "NoManSky.jpg"
        },
        {
            "IdJogo": "2",
            "Titulo": "Starbound",
            "DtaLancamento": "Dezembro 2013",
            "ResumoBR": "Starbound é um sandbox/open world, nele você vive     em uma espaçonave e pode explorar diferentes mundos, sistemas solares, galáxias, etc. As possibilidades são praticamente infinitas!",
            "NomeImg": "Starbound.jpg"
        }
```

Estou utilizando o Json.net (newtonsoftjson) para converter cada "Jogo" contido no Json para um *objeto* com os mesmos atributos existentes no Json, mas obtenho os mais diversos erros. Atualmente, faço a conversão dessa maneira:

```
string jsonR = resposta.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;                    

foreach (JObject elemento in jsonR)
{
    Game game = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Game>(elemento.ToString());  
}
```

Porem, me retorna o seguinte erro:

> Não é possivel converter um objeto do tipo Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue no tipo Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject

e quando tento colocar como tipo JValue dentro do foreach, obetnho o erro:

> Error converting value 123 to type 'WpfApplication1.Game'.Path ",line1 position 3.

Desculpe qualquer erro ao postar dessa forma, mas já revirei a documentação do Newtonsoft, já revirei o google e nada conseguiu me ajudar.

Comment: `...<Game>(elemento.ToString());`? Isso deveria mesmo ser assim?

Comment: Quando eu tiro o ToString já obtenho um erro nessa linha dizendo que não da para converter de Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject para string.

Comment: O metodo DeserializeObject aceita como parâmetro uma string Json.

Comment: Se você já tem um `JObject`, você pode chamar o método `ToObject<T>` em vez de convertê-lo pra string e depois converter aquela string para o seu objeto.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Primeiro alguns pontos, e ao final uma solução.

- Seu JSON é a representação de um objeto que possui uma propriedade, `games`, que por sua vez é uma coleção. Simplificado, ele pode ser expresso dessa maneira:

  `{ "games": []}`
- Essa coleção é formada por objetos simples (uma relação de propriedades com valores primitivos):

  `{"IdJogo": "","Titulo": "","DtaLancamento": "","ResumoBR": "","NomeImg": ""}`

Para que sua desserialização ocorra com sucesso, você precisa criar classes que representem estas entidades:

```
public class listaGames () {
    public List<itemGame> games {get; set;}
}

public class itemGame () {
    public string IdJogo {get;set;}
    public string Titulo {get; set;}
    public string DtaLancamento {get; set;}
    public string ResumoBR {get; set;}
    public string NomeImg {get; set;}
}
```

Com essas estruturas presentes, você pode agora desserializar o JSON:

```
string jsonR = resposta.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;                    

listaGames listagames = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<listaGames>(jsonR);
```

Como resultado, o objeto `listagames` terá sua propriedade *games* populada com instâncias da classe `itemGame`.

Comment: Putz, muito obrigado, cara. Se eu pudesse eu te daria um abraço.

Comment: @Fumegz Sempre um prazer ajudar, fico feliz que tenha funcionado. =)

Answer (score 7):

Crie o objeto com os campos desejados tipo:

```
struct ObjJogo
{
   public string IdJogo        { get; set; }
   public string Titulo        { get; set; }
   public string DtaLancamento { get; set; }
//-- e outros...
}
```

Depois pege a resposta em json e passe ela pelo código:

```
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
ObjJogo jsonData = js.Deserialize<ObjJogo>(RespostaWS);
```

Se vier um lista utilize o `List<ObjJogo>`

esta na `using System.Web.Script.Serialization;`

Espero que ajude, tive um problema parecido com esse e assim o resolvi.

Comment: Ajudou e muito, vi o problema de um outro angulo. Vlw mesmo!

Comment: Não por isso, é sempre um prazer poder ajudar

Answer (score 4):

O primeiro `foreach` está tentando converter o string `jsonR` em um `JValue` usando o conversor implícito. Você termina com uma string JSON, e não com um objeto, o que é o que você precisa.

Para ler usando o JSON.NET, você precisa primeiro fazer o parsing apropriado (i.e., de `jsonR` para um `JObject`). Depois você pode usar o método `ToObject<T>` para converter o objeto JSON para o seu tipo, como no exemplo abaixo.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var jo = JObject.Parse(jsonR);
        var games = jo["games"].ToObject<Game[]>();
        foreach (var game in games)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(game);
        }
    }

    const string jsonR = @"{
        ""games"": [
            {
                ""IdJogo"": ""1"",
                ""Titulo"": ""No Man's Sky"",
                ""DtaLancamento"": ""Junho 2016"",
                ""ResumoBR"": ""Em No Man's Sky  você assume o papel de um explorador planetário com uma nave espacial, permitindo-lhes explorar a superfície de vários planetas e interagir com a flora e fauna, e viajar pelo espaço, entrar em combate com forças inimigas e viajar a outros planetas."",
                ""NomeImg"": ""NoManSky.jpg""
            },
            {
                ""IdJogo"": ""2"",
                ""Titulo"": ""Starbound"",
                ""DtaLancamento"": ""Dezembro 2013"",
                ""ResumoBR"": ""Starbound é um sandbox/open world, nele você vive em uma espaçonave e pode explorar diferentes mundos, sistemas solares, galáxias, etc. As possibilidades são praticamente infinitas!"",
                ""NomeImg"": ""Starbound.jpg""
            }
        ]
    }";
}

public class Game
{
    public string IdJogo { get; set; }
    public string Titulo { get; set; }
    public string DtaLancamento { get; set; }
    public string ResumoBR { get; set; }
    public string NomeImg { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! Agora vou tenho duas soluções! Ambas testadas e aprovadas!